# Reliance net connect and ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mobile-broadband

I added recently purachased a reliance net connect broadband+. It has both balance and validity.

I connected it. It was detected.

I added a new mobile broadband connection. Chose the details properly

I edited the connection and provided user name and password

But it consistently fails to connect. I get an error that says there is some internal error with `/usr/sbin/modem-manager` but I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

Then I gave up and tried the instruction [here](http://dewdrops-rumbles.blogspot.in/2012/08/reliance-netconnect-and-ubuntu-1204.html). That is not working either. I am lost. Has anybody set up this model on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also got a Reliance Netconnect connection and mobile broadband support in linux via Network Manager is at best buggy. You could try using `wvdial` instead. Go through the following posts, you may need to change a couple of settings namely the username and password that Reliance gives you.

1. [Netconnect over wvdial](http://nikhilbhardwaj.in/2012/12/03/netconnect-settings-ubuntu/)
2. [Ubuntuformus post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1333535)

Hope this helps, if you want further clarifications feel free to ask.